# Flex Mobile Calendar component

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flex-mobile

I'm looking for Flex mobile calendar component, but I couldn't achieve any success. How can I implement its alternative or is there any available you have tried before?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'd love time to tweak our Calendar for use on mobile devices, but it hasn't been a priority.  I've spoken to at least one client who uses our comp on mobile devices: https://www.flextras.com/index.cfm?event=ProductHome&productID=15 . It's not optimized for that, though, so I Assume he must have done lots of tweaking and/or have simplified renderers.

Comment: It's not an ideal solution, but you can use StageWebView and then use one of the dozens of JavaScript calendars. Here's an article on the stageWebView: http://coenraets.org/blog/2011/07/flex-mobile-invoking-javascript-in-a-stagewebview/

Answer (score 0):

We just released our KC-Calendar component for Flex mobile.
Check it out here: http://www.flex-component.com/flex-components/mobile-kc-calendar